# Saving activity into pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to save Activity content into .pdf file. Something like a screenshot. I can save individual views of a activity into file using this code:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(600,300, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
View content = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);
```

But how to save (printscreen) whole activity, not just a views?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot of the current activity using the given code

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

}

and make sure give write permissions of the storage in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: The OP is specifically asking to save it as a PDF, not as a JPEG.